Could not find a package configuration file provided by cv2 with any of the following names: cv2Config.cmake cv2-config.cmake
I have tried the command catkin_create_pkg <package_name> cv2.
But whenever I prompt catkin_make, this error shows up. I'm not an expert on ROS, as I am just starting a project. I would appreciate any help.


Why are you adding a dependency on cv2? That's not a known ROS package nor a rosdep. Based on your tags it seems that you might want to be depending on opencv2 which is a rosdep key which can be resolved:
You can see where it resolves on ROSIndex rosdep opencv2
And then you're going to have to use rosdep to make sure that the dependency that you want is installed. Tutorial here
Other feedback, please don't share screenshots of code, copy and paste it so that it's readable and searchable. Typos in images are much harder to find. And please when you ask your question provide background info on what you're trying to achieve and what you've tried already to a level that someone can reproduce your problem. Otherwise we're just guessing.

Oh, I'm sorry about the formatting of my question.
And I got it now. The way that I understood the tutorial that I followed was that everything you imported should be declared in the XML file. So, somehow, I got it now that cv2 and other dependencies don't need to be declared. It's now working for me.
I was trying to create a customized topic since I'm trying to send specific data, but I don't know how to store it. So, I got stuck in the catkin_make part because of the cv2.
Everything is working fine now, so thanks a lot!
